# Why does spatzle dissolve in water?

Tags: food-science, german-cuisine

We've made spatzle a bunch of times with great success. Tonight, we put it in the boiling water like many times before, and it completely dissolved, resulting in cloudy water rather than anything resembling spatzle. We followed the recipe exactly. It's the first time making this at our new location, at a higher altitude, with colder and drier conditions and well water. What happened?

Comment: What is your altitude now?

Comment: We're at 930m or 3050ft

Comment: That's only 1deg lower in boiling temp, so I doubt altitude is making a difference.  My working hypothesis would be that you mismeasured something.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget the eggs or something? Because *túrógombóc* can absolutely dissolve in water, but I've never had it happen to *nokedli*.

Comment: (The problem with @FuzzyChef's hypothesis is, of course, that I have never in my life *measured* anything when making spaetzle/nokedli/galuska.)

Comment: Did you buy your ingredients at your new location, or at your old one? It might be worth looking for ways they're different - older/newer items, different brands, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A strong boil will break up the spaetzle batter. Keep it at a simmer.

Comment: Stronger bread flour works well for nokedli, to keep them firmer. I’d guess spätzle would be similar.